# Surjectivity of a functional equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anybody help me prove (or disprove) the surjectivity of this functional?

For all real $x$ and $y$:
$f(x+f(y))=f(x)+y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=0$, you have

$$ f(0) = f(f(y))-y $$

So $f(f(y)) = y+C$, hence $f \circ f$ is surjective, and this imply that $f$ is surjective

Comment: Perfect man! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$f(0)=f(-f(y)+f(y))=f(-f(y))+y$$
for every $y\in\Bbb R$.

Now take any $z\in\Bbb R$. Then
$$f(-f(f(0)-z))=f(0)-(f(0)-z)=z$$

So, $f$ is, indeed, surjective.